# how we can Insert Form Data into Database magento 2 through controller and model

Tags: magento2, forms

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); 
$exPrice=$_product->getData('ex_price');
?>
<?php if ($exPrice == true): ?>
<div class="note_1">
  <p><b style="color: red;">Note:</b> <span style="color: darkblue;">We don't have prices, because the prices depends on the sizes and the quantities</span></p>  
</div>

<div class="product-quote">
    <form class="product-qoute-form" action="quote/crud/save" id="my-form" data-mage-init='{"validation": {}}' method="post">
        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="row"> 
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="field name required">
                <div class="control">
                  <label for="" class="elementor-field-label">Company Name</label>
                  <input name="company" id="Company Name" title=" Company Name" placeholder="Company Name" value="" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true" required>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="field email required">
              <div class="control">
                <label for="" class="elementor-field-label">Email</label>
                <input name="email" id="email" title="Email" placeholder="Email" value="" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}" aria-required="true" required>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="row"> 
         
          <!-- <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="field name required">
                <div class="control">
                  <label for="" class="elementor-field-label">Company Name</label>
                  <input name="company" id="Company Name" title=" Company Name" placeholder="Company Name" value="" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true">
                </div>
              </div>
          </div> -->
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="field telephone">
              <div class="control">
                <label for="" class="elementor-field-label">Phone</label>
                <input name="telephone" id="telephone" placeholder="Telephone" title="Phone Number" type="text" required>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
           <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
             <div class="field name required">
              <div class="control">
                <label for="" class="elementor-field-label">Shipping Country</label>
                <input name="country" id="country" title=" country" placeholder="Country" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true" required> 
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <!--   <div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="row"> 
          
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="field name required">
                <div class="control">
                  <label for="" class="elementor-field-label">Width</label>
                  <input name="width" id="width" title=" width" placeholder="Width" value="" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true" required>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="field email required">
              <div class="control">
                <label for="" class="elementor-field-label">Height</label>
                <input name="height" id="height" title=" height" placeholder="Height" value="" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true" required>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> -->
        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="row"> 
          
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="field email required">
              <div class="control">
                <label for="" class="elementor-field-label">Quantity</label>
                <input name="quantity" id="Quantity" title=" quantity" placeholder="Quantity" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true" required>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="field name required">
                <div class="control">
                  <label for="" class="elementor-field-label">Depth</label>
                  <input name="depth" id="Depth" title=" depth" placeholder="Depth" value="" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true">
                </div>
              </div>
          </div> -->
        </div>
        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="row"> 
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="field email required">
              <div class="control">
                <label for="" class="elementor-field-label">Your message</label>
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Your message" title="Your message" cols="5" rows="3" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true" required></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="action-toolbar">
            <input type="hidden" name="sku" id="sku" value="<?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?>">
            <button id="btnSaveIt" type="submit" title="Submit" class="action primary tocart orange_1">
                <span>Request for Quote</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#my-form": {
            "validation": {}
        }
    }
</script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" async defer>
    require(["jquery","mage/mage","Magento_Ui/js/model/messageList"],function($) {
        
        var dataForm = $('#my-form');
        dataForm.mage('validation', {});
        
        $(document).ready(function() {
          
          $("#my-form").on("submit",function(){
             var status = dataForm.validation('isValid'); //validates form and returns boolean
             var get_data=dataForm.serialize();
             // alert($.type(get_data));
              if(status){
                console.log('form is validated'); //form is valid
                
                var comp_name=jQuery("input[name='company']").val();
                var email=jQuery("input[name='email']").val();
                var telephone=jQuery("input[name='telephone']").val();
                var country=jQuery("input[name='country']").val();
                var quantity=jQuery("input[name='quantity']").val();
                var msg=jQuery("#comment").val();
                // console.log(msg);            
                var sku=jQuery("input[name='sku']").val();
                var url = "<?php echo $this->getUrl().'quote/crud/save'?>";            
                jQuery.ajax({
                   url: url,
                   type: "post",
                   // dataType: "text",
                   // data:{quote:get_data},
                   data: {company:comp_name,email:email,telephone:telephone,country:country,quantity:quantity,comment:msg,sku:sku},
                   showLoader: true,
                   cache: false,
                   success: function(data){
                      if(data.response == 'added'){ // if true (1)
                          // setTimeout(function(){// wait for 5 secs(2)
                          //      window.location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
                          // }, 1000);
                          $("#my-form")[0].reset();
                          console.log('success');
                            // messageList.addSuccessMessage({
                            //   message: 'Quote Email Confirmation is successully sent'
                            // });
                          // alert('success'); 
                       }else{
                          alert('success is wrong'); 
                       }
          
                    },
                     error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error, "fail");
                     }
                });
                return false;
              }else{
              console.log('form is not validated');
              }
          });
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
.product-add-form{
  display: none;
}
.price-box{
  display: none;
}
.availability.only{
  display: none;
}
.product-info-main .product-info-stock-sku .attribute.sku {
     float: none !important; 
}
.action-toolbar{
  text-align: center;
}
.note_1{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.note_1 p{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
</style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is my code for save the form data in db**

```
<?php
    namespace Form\Quote\Controller\Crud;
    
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
    use Form\Quote\Model\QuoteFormFactory;
    class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
        /**
         * @var contact
         */
        protected $context;
        protected $resultFactory;
        protected $messageManager;
        protected $_quoteFactory;
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
            QuoteFormFactory $quoteFactory,
            \Form\Quote\Helper\Data $helper
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->_helper = $helper;
            $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
            $this->_quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
            // $this->_resultFactory = $resultFactory;
        }
    
        public function execute()
        {
            $Data=array();
    
            // 1. POST request : 
            $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            // var_dump($post);
            // die();
            if (!empty($post)) {
                // Retrieve your form data
                // Doing-something with...
    
                // Display the succes form validation message
                $Data['sku']=$post['sku'];
                // $Data['name']=$post['name'];
                $Data['email']=$post['email'];
                $Data['telephone']=$post['telephone'];
                $Data['company']=$post['company'];
                $Data['country']=$post['country'];
                $Data['quantity']=$post['quantity'];
                $Data['comment']=$post['comment'];
                $quoteData = $this->_quoteFactory->create();
                $quoteData->setData($Data);
                $quoteData->save();
                $this->_helper->sendEmail($Data);            
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Quote Email Confirmation is successully sent');
                // we are using ajax in phtml for checking the response of form 
                if (!empty($Data)) {
                    $response="added";
                }else{
                    $response="not added";
                }
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
                $resultRedirect->setData([
                    "response" => $response
                    // 'success' => true,
                    // 'message' => $this->messageManager->addSuccess("Quote Email Confirmation is successully sent")
                ]);
                return $resultRedirect;
                
                // die();
    
                //  // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
                // $resultRedirect->setUrl('/crud/save/');
                // reload the cotroller on same page means preveius page
                $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
                return $resultRedirect;
                }
            // 2. GET request : Render the booking page 
                $this->_view->loadLayout();
                $this->_view->renderLayout();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code i have make custom form and saved in custom table.Below code is as per my requirement. So Please controller and model code and parameter name change as per your.

**`.phtml file`** custom form code

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
        <form method="POST" action="<?= $this->getUrl('mcf/index/save'); ?>" id="mcf" role="form" name="RegForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-mage-init='{"validation":{"rules": {"field-2": {"required":true}}}}'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h2>Form</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml('Your Name') ?></span></label>
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" data-validate='{"required":true}'>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml('Your FirstName') ?></span></label>
                <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml('Your LastName') ?></span></label>
                <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml('Your  Address') ?></span></label>
                <input id="address" name="address" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="field-2"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml('Your Mobile Number') ?></span></label>
                <input id="mo_number" name="mo_number" type="text" class="form-control" data-validate='{"required":true, "validate-number": true}'>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml('Gender') ?></span></label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked>Male<br>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">FeMale<br>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other<br>
            </div>
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button type="submit" title="Submit" id="mcf-btn" class="action submit primary" data-mage-init='{"mcf_js":{}}'>
                        <span>Submit</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**`Mag\MCF\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js`**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*':{
                mcf_js:'Mag_MCF/js/mcf_js',
            }
        },
    shim:{
            'mcf_js':{
                                 deps: ['jquery']
                             }
        }
};
```

**`Mag\MCF\view\frontend\web\js\mcf_js.js`**

```
define(["jquery", "domReady!","mcf_js"], function($,dom,mcf_js){

    $(document).on('click', '#mcf-btn', function(e){
        var ajxurl = $('#mcf').attr('action');
        var formdata = new FormData(jQuery('#mcf')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: ajxurl,
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formdata,
            showLoader: true,
            success: function(data){
                location.reload();
                alert("Save");
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

})
```

To handle the POST method in your controller class, you have to implement the **`Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface`**

> Your Controller file

```
<?php

namespace Mag\MCF\Controller\Index;

use Mag\MCF\Model\McfFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;

class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements HttpPostActionInterface
{
    protected $_mcfFactory;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        McfFactory $mcfFactory
    ) {
        $this->_mcfFactory = $mcfFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $post_data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        try {
            $Mcfdata = $this->_mcfFactory->create();
            $Mcfdata->setData($post_data);
            $Mcfdata->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__("Save Data"));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('please try again. Form Not Submit'));
        }
    }
}
```

**`UPDATE`**

**`Mag\MCF\Model\DataExample.php`**

```
<?php 
namespace Mag\MCF\Model;
class DataExample extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel{
    public function _construct(){
        $this->_init("Mag\MCF\Model\ResourceModel\DataExample");
    }
}
 ?>
```

**`Mag\MCF\Model\ResourceModel\DataExample.php`**

```
<?php 
namespace Mag\MCF\Model\ResourceModel;
class DataExample extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb{
 public function _construct(){
 $this->_init("data_example","id");
 }
}
 ?>
```

**`Mag\MCF\Model\ResourceModel\Collection.php`**

```
<?php 
namespace Mag\MCF\Model\ResourceModel\DataExample;
class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection{
    public function _construct(){
        $this->_init("Mag\MCF\Model\DataExample","Mag\MCF\Model\ResourceModel\DataExample");
    }
}
 ?>
```

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Thanks Mohit for helpul comment can you share the model code

Comment: @MoazzamS i have updated my answer please check and let me know if any query.

Comment: Thanks Mohit if i have any problem then i will share you

Comment: Yes sure you will share.

Comment: Hi mohit i want to add admin grid in admin panel have you admin grid code for this form

Comment: can you help me for this addmin panel grid i have successully save the data in db though ajax